# How to inserting an intermediate row?

Tags: sql, t-sql

I have the following table:

```
Year    Line    January Febraury   March .... December
2011     B1       5       10         20
2012     B1      10       15         25         ...
2011     A1       4        8         10         ...
```

And I want to insert a subtotal row each two lines (if exists), in particular each time `year` and `Line` changing: so

```
Year    Line    January Febraury   March .... December
2011     B1        5       10         20
2012     B1       10       15         25         ...
 ---     B1     +100%   +50%       +25%      ..
2011     A1      4        8          10         ...
```

How can I do this in T-SQL ?

Maybe using cursor ?

Comment: If you post code, XML or **sample data**, **PLEASE** highlight those lines in the text editor and click on the "code samples" button ( `{  }` ) on the editor toolbar to nicely format and syntax highlight it!

Comment: This is something you shouldn't be doing in T-SQL - use a reporting tool (like Reporting Services) or handle this in your front-end application - *not* in the database!

Comment: I answered before your edit.  What should the summary line look like when you have 3 years of data?  And being that these are different data type (INTs and then percentages [float or decimal?]), do you mean a query rather than an insert?

Comment: Hi, the problem is that i can't do in Reporting services !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you *certain* that you want to insert a new row?  Or just be able to calculate that subtotal when you query the data?

***Query Version***

```
SELECT
  Year,
  Line,
  SUM(January)      AS January,
  SUM(February)     AS February,
  ...
  SUM(December)     AS December
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  Year,
  Line
WITH
  ROLLUP
ORDER BY
  Year,
  Line
```

**Insert Version**

If you just one one level of summary, remove the `WITH ROLLUP`

```
INSERT INTO
  yourTable
SELECT
  Year,
  NULL,
  SUM(January)      AS January,
  SUM(February)     AS February,
  ...
  SUM(December)     AS December
FROM
  yourTable
GROUP BY
  Year
WITH
  ROLLUP
```

**EDIT** Follow question edit

I strongly suggest that you mean a query, not a change to the actual data.  I also suggest that you either build these lines in your reporting environment, or you put the % values to the right of each record...

```
SELECT
  this_year.Year,
  this_year.Line,
  this_year.January,
  CAST(this_year.January AS DECIMAL(8,2)) / CAST(last_year.January AS DECIMAL(8,2)) AS January_Change,
  ...
FROM
  yourTable   AS this_year
LEFT JOIN
  yourTable   AS last_year
    ON  last_year.year = this_year.year-1
    AND last_year.line = this_year.line
```